# Is there a code which inserts semi colon at the start of every record in field ( zapier_python_hubspot) project

Tags: python, integration, zapier, hubspot, airtable

I am in the process of integrating my airtable databas to Hubspot crm and would want to extract information from record in a fields . The problem is the data in the record is seperated by comma, while Hubspot accepts data seperated by semi colon( from the start of each record).
Can someone please help me with a python code?

example: from "scissors,hedgers,clippers"  to ";scissors;hedgers;clippers"

Comment: record=record.replace(",",";")

Comment: Thank you for responding, but the dict function does not have the attribute replace.

Comment: Since you did not share the code, It is hard to guess your data structure. Feel free to add a part of your code, maybe I can help